# Are east and north facing homes considered best while west and South facing an ill omen?

Tags: scripture, vastu-shastra, omens

Local people tell that as per Vastu, a house built must face its main entrance towards the North or most importantly East. They tell West is avoided while South facing home is bad luck and evil and results in death. Is it True?

In which place (scripture) it is written? Please explain.

Comment: NorthEast (Ishana) is the head of Vastu Purusha of a house so mostly it is preferred that a house faces North or East...

Comment: East is direction of Indra/power, North is Kubera/wealth and NE is most auspicious due to Ishana. Maybe Vastu scriptures mention this

Comment: Ashta linga also represents ishana linga in north east. @TheDestroyer . Thus north north east is preferred.